# Compute the following summation using n-1 and k

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose k}$$

I have only done this before with integers instead of n-1, and generally the format has an expression after the choose part, so I'm not entirely sure how to begin here.

Comment: I suggest just computing it for the first few $n$, the pattern will be obvious.

Comment: Consider applying the binomial theorem to (1 + 1)^n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $2^n$ is the summation of $n\choose r$ (taking both the binomial numbers as $1$)
then
just change the value of $n\to n-1$ and it will end up being $2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Ohh thank you!! I didnt realize I could do it with both binomial numbers as 1.